# How to pass list argument to TCL array get?

Tags: arrays, tcl

So, I have array:

```
 set b(1,2,3,4) 5
```

and I can get its element using

```
   array get b {1,2,3,4}
```

#but I can't find the way to pass that key list argument
   # as a previously defined variable

```
set x { 1 2 3 4}
array get b x  #does not work
array get b $x #does not work
```

How to do it?

Comment: Don't use `array get` to fetch single values out of arrays; it is a command that fetches many values in one operation, and is therefore relatively expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `{ 1 2 3 4}` is not equal to `1,2,3,4`.

```
% set x 1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
% array get b $x
1,2,3,4 5
% set b($x)
5
```

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm)